# Conditional formatting for specific group of values/rows based on cell value(s)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016

I am having some data table that is separated in lets say "blocks" of rows. As you can see on the image, starting from Column D (A1) there are some values in first row, and then 5 rows empty and again on 7th row values and so on...that is what I am calling a block of rows, always in the sam interval.

[image: Example]
What I wanted to accomplish is next:

1. Column I (D1) should be my "filter" column where I wanna choose some values, one or more doesnt matter.
2. When I have chosen some "values", the data is bein filtered as normally in Excel Tables, but I wanted to have the possibility to always leave visible that block of rows which is matched, not only row or two, but whole block even though 90% will be blank cells or not. The rest can be deleted or hidden but with possibility to have them back on selection or deselection
3. Important is to keep always block of those 6 rows, or can be two or three blocks if the values are included in other blocks. And when there is not match in other blocks, that should be "hidden"
4. I tried with helper columns like in Column A, B and C but no success, tried to combine them somehow but no success.
5. Of course I added color to mark them but it can be also without it, important is that filter is 100% correct.

Helper1:

```
=MOD(SUMPRODUCT(($D$5:$D5<>$D$4:$D4)*1);2)=0
```

This is what is now in CF as a formula:

```
=$I5=$I$3
```

I am not skilled in VBA if that is an option, but from other side I have seen that is possible to do this using CF also...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it helpful to create an index for the "group" of 6 rows, with this formula:

```
=ROUNDUP((ROW()-1)/6,0)
```

[image]

I'm sure there are several ways to do this next part, but this is the one that occurred to me first.

Count the rows that have the same group as the current row and where the value(s) in column D can be found in the filter list in column J. Because the filter list can be more than one cell, this would return an array of length the same as the filter list and where each item is an integer representing the count of that filter item in the group. So, if the group contained `0528` twice, and `0342` once, and the filter was to find both `0528` and `0342`, then the `COUNTIF` would return `{2,1}`:

I've used `TRANSPOSE` here to illustrate the results of each row. This formula is in column G:

```
=TRANSPOSE(COUNTIFS($E$2:$E$19,$E2,$D$2:$D$19,$J$1:$J$2)
```

[image]

So, if I just want a single value to indicate that a row has found something, I can sum that array and compare the sum to 0. If the sum is greater than zero, then I found at least one filter item in the group, and then the whole group can be filtered.

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS($E$2:$E$19,$E2,$D$2:$D$19,$H$1:$H$2))>0
```

Note that the `TRANSPOSE` is not really necessary, so I've removed it.

[image]

We could probably embed the group calculation in the filter formula, but I think it would be better to leave it where it is as it may be useful for other calculations.

Comment: Oh man! This was basically what I wanted to. It opens me a new way to achieve my goals, using conditional formatting, record macro and some playaround will get me where I wanted. I knew it was tough thing, but thanks for your great input!!!